# JAVA TEST java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I use JUnit4 i added from the java buld path But still i have a error.
I want to Complete the code to insert 3 books (ouvrage) in the catalog (Catalogue) And then Run your code using junit.
I use JUnit4 i added from the java buld path But still i have a error.
I want to Complete the code to insert 3 books (ouvrage) in the catalog (Catalogue) And then Run your code using junit.
I use JUnit4 i added from the java buld path But still i have a error.
I want to Complete the code to insert 3 books (ouvrage) in the catalog (Catalogue) And then Run your code using junit.

```
package fr.univrouen.bibliotheque.test; 
//package fr.univrouen.bibliotheque.util;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test ;
import fr.univrouen.bibliotheque.*;



public class CatalogueTest {

    Catalogue MonCatalogue = BibliothequeFactory.eINSTANCE.createCatalogue();
    Ouvrage Ovr1 = BibliothequeFactory.eINSTANCE.createOuvrage();
    Ouvrage Ovr3 = BibliothequeFactory.eINSTANCE.createOuvrage();
    Ouvrage Ovr2 = BibliothequeFactory.eINSTANCE.createOuvrage();

    @Test
    public void Test() {

    MonCatalogue.setNom("Biblio");

    Ovr1.setAuteur("fouad");
    Ovr1.setTitre("Tuto1");
    Ovr1.setCategorie(Categorie.DOCUMENTAIRE);



    Ovr2.setAuteur("david");
    Ovr2.setTitre("Tuto2");
    Ovr2.setCategorie(Categorie.DOCUMENTAIRE);



    Ovr3.setAuteur("saad");
    Ovr3.setTitre("Tuto3");
    Ovr3.setCategorie(Categorie.DOCUMENTAIRE);


    MonCatalogue.ajoutOuvrage(Ovr1);
    MonCatalogue.ajoutOuvrage(Ovr2);
    MonCatalogue.ajoutOuvrage(Ovr3);

    assertEquals(0, 0); 

    }
}
```

I Have this ERROR

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadTestLoaderClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Show a screenshot that shows `org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter` being on the Java Build Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding @RunWith annotation to your class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)    
public class CatalogueTest {
...
```